# Which FileSystemRights enum would renaming a file be?

Tags: c#, rename

Question is in the title... C#

Trying to prevent renaming of a folder, I tried using a filesystemwatcher and having an void on the rename event which would rename the folder back, but it caused a forkbomb.

I decided just to quit that and use access rights, but which one would renaming a file/folder be under?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In NTFS, in order to rename a file/folder, you must have delete privs.  This is included in the broader set of permissions known as "modify".  Obviously this is a pain, but there you are.

So, if you remove a group's or user's delete privileges on a folder, they will not be able to rename it.

Comment: That's not right, I have set the privileges to FileSystemRights.Delete | FileSystemRights.DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles and I am still able to rename without adjusting the privileges.

Comment: @user2444664 is right this won't work, I've tried it. This question still needs an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileSystemRights.FullControl
```

Is the only one that will deny a rename. I know because I literally denied every other one on a file and I was still able to rename it.

So you're (and me) are out of luck if you want to deny rename and allow anything. For example allowing read after denying full control won't allow read. This seems to be a serious design flaw. I'll need to find some other way to accomplish this.